# Turn on UNLOGGED for any new table creation under a specific schema

Tags: postgresql

I understand I can turn on UNLOGGED with each table creation SQL. However in my scenario it means I need to make sure my team members and I remember to do that every time when creating a table. Want to know if I can make UNLOGGED by default for a specific schema or even or whole db is fine.

Comment: Not possible, unless you change the source code and build your own version of PostgreSQL. You could however use ALTER TABLE for every table in your database and set it to unlogged.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked the doc and found no luck. Now I can stop worrying if I missed anything.